# Force garbage collection in remote CLR process

Tags: c#, .net, profiling

I have a simple custom memory profiler based on CLRMD library. It works fine and all. But I have to always force GC manually from inside my target application in order to get accurate counts of objects. Is there a simple way to trigger GC of a CLR process on my machine from another process?
My first thought is to use remoting of some kind to tell the target process to perform GC. But this will require modification of the target, which is not good idea.

Comment: I don't know why this is down voted. Commercial memory profilers are running forced GC before taking snapshot, but how ? And I am also searching for the solution. Please post if you found one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the target application is yours, you can run it using custom CLR host, implement `ICLRGCManager`, and invoke its' `Collect` method from "outside" of managed code.

You would still need some kind of remote control or trigger to do this, 
*but* you can export a C-style procedure to call it, and `GetProcAddress` that from your profiler, bypassing managed control completely (I never tried that in C#, just in Delphi, but it should work).

See http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2005/07/24/2984.aspx for some beautiful explanations (kudos to Bart De Smet).